# What does the 'belt' Orochimaru and the Sound Four wear signify?

Tags: naruto

The Sound Four wear a purple-colored type of *belt* or *wrap* around their waists:

[image]

Orochimaru, their master, also wore one:

[image]

Being some of the few ninja I have seen wearing one, does it have a formal name? What does it signify and does it relate or exist in real world fighting..? *It feels almost sumo-ish, I think.*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The belt they are wearing is generally referred to as an "obi."

The belt braided in the style of [Shimenawa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shimenawa) ropes, sacred Shinto ropes made by twisting together straws. It is hung horizontally to indicate a sacred Shintoism place such as praying hall or torii.

The Wikipedia article (linked above) notes that:

> A variation of the shimenawa is used in [sumo wrestling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sumo_wrestling) by [yokozuna](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yokozuna_%28sumo%29) (grand champions) during their entrance ceremonies to denote their rank. This is because the yokozuna is seen as a living yorishiro (formally [shintai](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shintai)), and as such is inhabited by a spirit.

Comment: Do you know if it signifies anything as it relates to Orochimaru.. why he wears one? I will accept for rank, that makes sense and thanks for the name, but the sumo bit throws it off somewhat.. still curious :)

Comment: I don't think it's mentions specifically, but I believe it's more for prestige showing readers that they are stronger than average and they shouldn't be crossed easily.